# Wrong EditText get focus in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I've got EditText's in ListView. After clicking next when focus is on first item focus is lost and next button change to new line button. On other items everything works as it suppose.

My list row layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/field_row_height">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/field"
        style="@style/EditText.Form.Field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_default_padding"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/required"
        style="@style/Button.Gray"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/required_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/required_button_height"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="@string/form_field_required"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

[image: before]
[image: after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/field_row_height">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field"
            style="@style/EditText.Form.Field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_default_padding">
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/required"
            style="@style/Button.Gray"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/required_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/required_button_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/form_field_required"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>




listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS); android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"          in your activity or android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Note that it is layout of rows in ListView.

Comment: consider these three line android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_default_padding">  //still open edittext
<requestFocus />  //for focus
</EditText>    //close edittext block

Comment: I see it but it doesn't help.

Comment: listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);                               android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"             in your activity or   android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

Comment: listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);  it helps! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/field"
        style="@style/EditText.Form.Field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_default_padding"/>
```

you forgot this

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: It has not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you put request focus whenever view is getting open requested widget get focus.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/field"
            style="@style/EditText.Form.Field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_default_padding">
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: I know how to transfer focus. The only problem is that it doesn't transfer focus between first end second row but does on the others.